# Delete all named ranges except for defined list

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to delete all named ranges out of an excel file, except for a defined list of named ranges(approximately 1000). Basically, if any tabs get copied into the file, I want to delete everything that has been copied in over time and only keep the original named ranges.

I've tried putting some code together below, but I am not quite advanced enough in VBA to understand where I am going wrong. It is currently giving me an error at the rName.Delete line, and I would like to somehow add an Array for the list to not delete instead of being defined in the code individually.

```
Sub DeleteNamedRanges()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Dim all_names, n
Dim rName As Name
For Each rName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If rName.Name <> "NamedRange1" And rName.Name <> "NamedRange2" 
    Then
        rName.Delete
End If
Next rName
End Sub
```

Comment: What error is it giving you?  When loopingo ver a collection and deleting items, it's best to work from the end back to the start ie. `For i = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1` then check `ActiveWorkbook.Names(i)` in your loop

Comment: @TimWilliams interestingly, a `For Each` loop captures the collection only once, so OP's code *should* work perfectly fine without any issues (as a matter of fact, I just now tested it, and it works). Iterating backwards is a good solution for a `For....Next` loop that's altering the collection though.

Comment: Do you actually have the `Then` token on a separate line? That can't compile...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I was thinking of things I've seen such as the "notes" here https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/20563/removing-items-from-a-collection (not to make any claim about the reliability of that reference one way or the other)

Comment: @TimWilliams there's a difference: `Collection.Remove` takes an `Index` argument; here we're looking at a `Name` object *that knows how to delete itself*, no index gets involved. Same applies to e.g. `ListRow.Delete`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - good point.  I guess i have internalized a bunch of "may not be a good idea" suggestions which may not actually be supported by the facts, so more like a defensive patterm on my part,  and also not being confident that any  "small c" collections (i.e similar behaviour but not instances of the built-in VBA Collection class)  behave exactly like the "big C" VBA Collection...

Comment: @TimWilliams the behavior is independent of the type involved though: language specifications for the `For Each` statement mandate that the collection expression is only captured once, when the loop is entered. But then again, that very same specification page also mandates that the loop variable still holds a reference to the last item in the collection when the loop exits, and that's provably not implemented, so... there's the specs, and then there's the actual implementation - but as far as I can tell the part about single-capture of the collection object is correct.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - good point about the `For Each` specs - that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - yes but who wants to be normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping over a collection and deleting items, it's [possibly - see discussion above] best to work from the end back to the start i.e. something like this:

```
Sub DeleteNamedRanges()

    Dim n As Long, arrKeep

    'names to not delete
    arrKeep = Array("keepThis", "andThis", "meToo")

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For n = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
        With ActiveWorkbook.Names(n)
            'is this name a keeper?
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Name, arrKeep, 0)) Then
                On Error Resume Next 'ignore any errors
                .Delete
                On Error Goto 0      'stop ignoring errors
            End If
        End With
    Next n

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!
I am getting a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error on the ".Delete" line of the If statement. Should there be something before the ".Delete"?

Comment: Or do any of your names refer to Tables/Listobjects?

Comment: Yes there are sheets that are protected, is there a way to skip over it if the sheet is protected?

Comment: See my edits above for the lazy way to ignore non-deletable names